# UITextView with attributedText causes an error in Swift 3

Tags: ios, textview, nsattributedstring

I did not know exactly where the error is hidden, but I think I spotted the cause of the error. The error is that when I type an attributed word or attributed words, they are highlighted in color. And then after those words are highlighted, I cannot write words like in the middle or at the start of the sentence. Right after an attributed `String`, all words which are entered are forced to be at the last of my TextView.  Why?

```
   for i in 0...searchString.count-1 {

        let string : String = searchString.object(at: i) as! String
        var range = NSRange(location: 0, length: attrStr.length)

        while (range.location != NSNotFound) {

            range = (attrStr.string as NSString).range(of: string, options: [], range: range)

            if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
   range = NSRange(location: range.location + range.length, length: inputLength - (range.location + range.length))
                attrStr.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20), range: range)
                myTextView.attributedText = attrStr
       }




    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {

    myTextView.textColor = UIColor.black

}

func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        let uuid = UUID().uuidString

        if !textView.text.isEmpty {
            self.singleton.edittText(text: self.myTextView.text!)
        }

        self.singleton.addText(text: self.myTextView.text)


        self.myTextView.resignFirstResponder()

    }

    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}

func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {

    highlightColors(words)

    let maxHeight = 80.0  
    if(myTextView.frame.size.height.native < maxHeight) {
        _ = myTextView.sizeThatFits(myTextView.frame.size)
    }
}
```

**Update**

Comment: Why are you calling `sizeThatFits`? Never call that. If you want to force the view to size itself, call `sizeToFit`.

Comment: @rmaddy well, even though I deleted, it did not work... Do you have any idea? When a word becomes attributed, this occurs...

Comment: Please update your question with relevant details.